tensorflow tf.function decorator and convergence
I am using a fully connected Neural Network as a function approximator in a more complex model. When I set up the model using the functional API I get convergence to a proper solution and the neural net does the job.
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(setupDict['inputShape'],), name='input')
x1 = keras.layers.Dense(setupDict['layerNodes'][0], activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', name='hidden1')(inputs)
x2 = keras.layers.Dense(setupDict['layerNodes'][1], activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', name='hidden2')(x1)
output1 = keras.layers.Dense(1, kernel_initializer='he_normal', name='outputD')(x2)
output1 = LogisticActivation(0.15, 1.5, 5, 'debt')(output1)
output2 = keras.layers.Dense(1, kernel_initializer='he_normal', name='outputS')(x2)
output2 = LogisticActivation(0.005, 6, 10, 'stab')(output2)
output3 = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='softplus', kernel_initializer='he_normal', bias_initializer='ones', name='outputV')(x2)
outputs = keras.layers.concatenate([output1, output2, output3], name='concatAll')
# Define the model
model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs,
                    outputs=outputs)

As there are some more complex use cases I wanted to port this to model subclassing and work with graph execution via tf.function. This is now where things get odd. I subclassed the model class and rewrote it in the follwoing way:

class defaultFreeModel(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, econDict, setupDict, GHDict, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.econDict = econDict
        self.setupDict = setupDict
        self.GHDict = GHDict
        # Layers
        self.hidden1 = keras.layers.Dense(setupDict['layerNodes'][0], activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', name='hidden1')
        self.hidden2 = keras.layers.Dense(setupDict['layerNodes'][1], activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', name='hidden2')
        self.output1tmp = keras.layers.Dense(1, kernel_initializer='he_normal', name='outputD')
        self.output1 = LogisticActivation(0.15, 1.5, 5, 'debt')
        self.output2tmp = keras.layers.Dense(1, kernel_initializer='he_normal', name='outputS')
        self.output2 = LogisticActivation(0.005, 6, 10, 'stab')
        self.output3 = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='softplus', kernel_initializer='he_normal', bias_initializer='ones',
                                     name='outputV')
        self.outputs = keras.layers.Concatenate()


    def call(self, inputs):
        x = self.hidden1(inputs)
        x = self.hidden2(x)
        x1 = self.output1tmp(x)
        x1 = self.output1(x1)
        x2 = self.output2tmp(x)
        x2 = self.output2(x2)
        x3 = self.output3(x)
        return self.outputs([x1, x2, x3])

    def compile(self, optimizer, loss_fn):
        super().compile()
        self.optimizer = optimizer
        self.loss_fn = loss_fn

If I run this model with my training loop, everything works fine, and I again get a proper solution. However, if I decorate the call function with tf.function in order to speed up the execution, there is no convergence anymore, and I do not get a solution. Does anyone know what the reason for this could be? The Gradient function is not decorated with tf.function, only the call.
As soon as I decorate the function with tf.function and run the training loop, the loss value stops going down and instead just hovers around some value (Different for each run due to the initializer).
As a test, I also decorated the gradient function with tf.function which would enable full graph execution. This actually speeds up computation substantially but also doesnt converge.
EDIT:
Here is the code of the Layer:
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
class LogisticActivation(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, level, slope, upper, name):
        super().__init__()
        self.slope = tf.constant(slope, dtype=tf.float32, name=name + "_slope")
        self.level = tf.constant(level, dtype=tf.float32, name=name + "_level")
        self.upper = tf.constant(upper, dtype=tf.float32, name=name + "_upper")

    @tf.function
    def call(self, inputs):
        return tf.divide(tf.multiply(self.level, self.upper), tf.constant(1, dtype=tf.float32)+tf.exp(-self.slope*(inputs-self.level)))

    def get_config(self):
        return {'level': self.level, 'slope': self.slope, 'upper': self.upper}


Hi can I see you the code of your LogisticActivation class please?

Added the code for the custom Layer.

Your code is ok, but here are some issues that I found from looking at the docs on tensor flow. It is better to use tf.Variable
You can do this modify the get_config function
def get_config(self):
    config = super().get_config()
    config.update({
         'level': self.level.numpy(),   # Convert to Python scalar
         'slope': self.slope.numpy(),   # Convert to Python scalar
          'upper': self.upper.numpy()    # Convert to Python scalar
        })
    return config


Thank you very much for the answer. I agree that the tf.constant is not perfect here. Regarding the activation layer. The 3 parameters are not 'trainable variables but rather constants which is why they are hardcoded. It's basically a generalitation of the sigmoid activation function.
In a similar model without any custom layers I had similar issues. When I decorate the call method with tf.function the gradients are None. I still investigating but I have modfied the config file as suggested. thank you.

@OliverK ok , so what function did you use to deteremine the tf.constant?
